# Is it recommended to move all windows software and personal files over to the ubuntu folder when using WSL2?

Tags: filesystem, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I just started studying robotics and started looking into the Linux world since a lot of people were recommending it. But I was dependent on a lot of Windows software which had terrible support in Ubuntu (or not support at all). So I decided to use WSL 2.

But I dont really understand how the file management between Windows and the Ubuntu installation is done. From my understanding, the Linux folder works like a partition on my C-drive in which all Linux-related stuff is stored. Therefore you generally want to store the files you perform tasks on with the command line in the Linux/ubuntu folder for better performance? (Please tell me if I'm wrong about this)

Like this [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/filesystems) says:

> For the fastest performance speed, store your files in the WSL file system if you are working in a Linux command line (Ubuntu, OpenSUSE, etc). If you're working in a Windows command line (PowerShell, Command Prompt), store your files in the Windows file system.

I have read and watched tutorials about how to use the command line and package manager effectively, and want to start using them for my projects. All my projects, interpreters/compilers, and text editors are currently on the Windows installation. Let's say I now move these files over to the Ubuntu folder and get an increase in performance/speed when using the command line. Great!

But let's say I want to start using the command line to control my entire system with all my software and files originally installed on Windows. Should I then move all my software and personal files over to the Ubuntu installation?
Will this cause problems if software is installed for a Windows system? Take Unreal Engine, for example, This software is optimized for Windows and I installed it for a Windows system when downloading it from Epic Games. Will moving this software over to the Ubuntu folder cause problems? Would it be the equivalent of trying to install an unreal engine Windows installation on a pure Ubuntu installation? (no WSL)

Also, if you have any recommended reads and sources for new Linux users to share. I would be happy to learn!

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with the question title and work from there:

> Is it recommended to move all Windows software and personal files over to the Ubuntu folder when using WSL2?

Simply, no.

> All my projects, interpreters/compilers, and text editors are currently on the Windows installation. Let's say I now move these files over to the Ubuntu folder and get an increase in performance/speed when using the command line.

It's a bit unclear what you mean by "increase in performance/speed when using the command-line.  There's nothing in WSL2 that is going to make it inherently faster than running a Windows application.  In fact, it may be slower.  WSL2/Ubuntu data is stored in a virtual SDD, which will never be as fast as the native Windows filesystem on which it is stored.

When accessing Windows files from Ubuntu, or vice-versa, WSL2 uses the Plan9 (9P) network filesystem.  This is yet *another* level of indirection that will slow performance.

In terms of performance, the ranking would go:

- Fastest:  Windows applications accessing files/data on the Windows drive.
- Fast(ish): Linux applications in WSL2/Ubuntu accessing files/data in the WSL2 filesystem.
- Slower: Windows applications accessing files/data in the WSL2 filesystem.
- Slowest: Linux applications applications in WSL2/Ubuntu accessing files/data on the Windows filesystem.

Now typically the speed difference isn't going to make a difference unless your application is pretty data intensive.  But if you start reading or writing to hundreds of files in your application, you'll start to notice it.

I don't use Unreal Engine, but I would expect that a common use case is for it to be reading many models.  If that's the case, then you don't want your data (or the application) to be on the Ubuntu virtual filesystem.

Now you *could* install the Linux version of Unreal Engine under Ubuntu in WSL2, but I'd recommend against that as well.  While Linux GUI applications can run in WSL2, they are definitely "second class" when it comes to features and performance.

Focus on running Ubuntu/Linux apps in WSL2 where:

- The application is terminal/console based (e.g., Vim, Node.js and related build tools, etc.)
- Or there's no good GUI alternative available in Windows
- The Linux version is better supported, has features that you need that aren't available in Windows, etc.

For *those* applications, install the Linux versions in Ubuntu under WSL2 along with their data.

---

Side-note:  As mentioned above, you can run the Windows version of any application from the command-line in Ubuntu under WSL2.  However, if it's not in your Windows path, you'll need to provide the full path, using the Linux directory structure.  You'll also need to provide the extension (`.exe`).

For instance, to run Notepad:

```
/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/notepad.exe
```

Or (assuming the top Google results is correct):

```
/mnt/c/Program\ Files\Epic\ Games\UE_5.1\Engine\Binaries\Win64\UnrealEditor.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

If you by "move over" imply just moving the current files over;
then you're in for a pure failure - unless you have software that interprets the files in exactly the same manner (e.g. a compiler).

Pulling over source code and compiling, then running will work though - assuming that source code is written in a style that allows it to be compiled for Linux.

**Where to gain knowledge:**
Windows cmd.exe is old and peculiar, the command "Shell" of Linux:en might be seen as corresponding to it, there are several variants but the one usually installed with Ubuntu is "Bash".
[www.tldp.org](http://www.tldp.org) has a couple "Bash guides" that can be a good browse through for a beginner, they're a bit old but still perfectly valid.

The shell can be seen as the basics of Linux, with a multitude of possibilities to automate and tweak. The GUI is software (Window Manager) has all the general options, but seldom allow the same amount of control. There are several optional versions there too. I can't tell if that is a possibility in WSL though.

*One thing to point out:*
Text files or source code are perfectly possible to transfer between, with one thing to keep in mind though: Windows uses CR+LF for line endings, Linux is LF only.
`unix2dos` and `dos2unix` are shell commands to use for the conversion.

`$ sudo apt install dos2unix` # to install both of those.

Comment: Okay, so software built for Windows systems is compiled in a specific way so the Windows kernel can work with it. While a Linux compiler will compile in such a way that the Linux kernel can work with it. Therefore, the compiled files (binaries) can not be exchanged between the operating systems. If I try to transfer all the Windows software over to the Ubuntu folder (without recompiling the source code). The software won't work since the Linux kernel won't understand the binaries. Is this correct? I just wanted to make sure I understood your answer.

Comment: Exactly so. There are e.g. "Wine" to run Windows software on Linux, but you must see that as an "emulator" which implies speed or functional penalties or incapabilities.

Comment: @volticus Not quite - A Windows application (`.exe`) that is moved to the WSL2/Ubuntu filesystem will still run as a *Windows* application.  For example, you *can* install the Windows version of Unreal Engine into the Ubuntu/WSL2 filesystem, and because of the WSL interop, it's still going to run.  However, it's going to actually be much *slower*, since it's a Windows application stored on a virtual SDD that is stored on the Windows drive.  It's much faster to leave it where it is on the *Windows* drive and avoid that level of virtualization.

Comment: I have no isight into WSL whatsoever, other than it being an "Ubuntu derivate". So; That is then an obvious "exception" in WSL from the Linux "normal". I get the impression there is sensing whether it is a Windows executable or not, and the related runtime environment is selected just as you choose to run Java, Python or ELF-binary (Linux default) executables with the proper interpreter or whatever. So; WSL is an abomination, mixed breed.